# How to fade MediaElement Volume by Storyboard

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8.1, windows-8.1, win-universal-app

Here my StoryBoard

```
    <Storyboard x:Name="SB_BattleSound">
        <DoubleAnimation
            x:Name="BattleSound"
            Duration="0:0:0.5"
            Storyboard.TargetProperty="(MediaElement.Volume)" 
            Storyboard.TargetName="battle" 
            d:IsOptimized="True">
        </DoubleAnimation>
    </Storyboard>
```

Here the MediaElement

```
<MediaElement x:Name="battle" Source="Assets/Sounds/battle.mp3" Volume="0.0" IsLooping="True" AutoPlay="True" Height="0" Width="0" />
```

And here the fade start

```
BattleSound.From = 0.0;
BattleSound.To = 0.8;
SB_BattleSound.Begin();
```

No errors but also no effect. I guess there is something wong with the target property or not?

Comment: Did you try `Storyboard.TargetProperty="Volume"`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set EnableDependentAnimation="True" on your animation. By default only animations which the system can tell won't cause a dependency between the rendering and UI threads will run. Animating properties which aren't explicitly known to be safe is disabled unless the app explicitly enables them.

See [Dependent and independent animations](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/jj819807.aspx#dependent) in the [Storyboarded animations](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/jj819807.aspx) documentation on MSDN for more details.

This works as I think you want:

```
<Storyboard x:Name="SB_BattleSound">
    <DoubleAnimation
    x:Name="BattleSound"
    Duration="0:0:0.5"
    Storyboard.TargetProperty="(MediaElement.Volume)" 
    Storyboard.TargetName="battle" 
    EnableDependentAnimation="True" 
    d:IsOptimized="True">
    </DoubleAnimation>
</Storyboard>
```

Comment: Thank you Rob. I had just bad experience with this option on low end smartphones.

Comment: Yes. That is why dependent animations are disabled by default. You need to be careful about the performance when using them and very deliberate about when they are worth it to your app and when you can use other more performant behavior